# Load Google maps v3 via xhr with error handling

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I would like to use Google maps V3 in a jQuery mobile application but am struggling to ensure that Google maps has loaded.

I would basically like to load Google Maps via xhr so that I can handle a timeout on the request. The regular way of adding the script tag into the head of you page has a callback but this assumes that the file was successfully fetched.

Is there any way of either loading the maps libs via xhr or handling a failed script tag load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle `onerror` event.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
$(script).attr("type", "text/javascript");
script.onerror = function(event){ 
   //************
   //ERROR OCCURED
   //************
}
script.onload = function(event){
   //Script loaded
}
script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false";
```

Comment: That was a life saver for me. Just had to add `document.body.appendChild(script);` Thank you!